# Перечисление в С++

Tags: c++

Как использовать enum?
Пример,

```
enum stat {WIN,LOSE,CONT};

switch (stat)
                {
                    case WIN: break;
                    case LOSE: break;
                    case CONT: break;
                }
```

И этот код не работает, потому что как оказывается `stat`, это тип переменных `WIN,LOSE,CONT` Так как тогда мне реализовать `switch` с перечислением?

Comment: В данном случае вы просто создали новый тип stat, но чтобы его использовать вам необходимо объявить переменную этого типа и проинициализировать её начальным значением.

Comment: А еще есть такая функция в Linux: stat, поэтому рекомендую вам переименовать ваш enum, чтобы не было конфликтов имен.

Comment: Хорошо :) Сам под виндой, но возьму на заметку.

Comment: @vladimir_ki чтобы не было конфликта, используют ключевые слова `enum stat variable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

enum Stat
{
    WIN, LOSE, CONT
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Stat value = LOSE;

    switch (value)
    {
        case WIN:
            throw std::invalid_argument("'WIN' is invalid here.");
            break;
        case LOSE:
            std::cout << "Everything is fine.";
            break;
        case CONT:
            throw std::invalid_argument("'CONT' is invalid here.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

В общем случае Вам нужна переменная типа Вашего перечисления. Например, имеем определение типа:

```
enum TColor {red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet};
```

тогда

```
switch (TColor)
{
 case red:
 break;
 case orange:
 break;
 case yellow:
 break;
 case green:
 break;
 case blue:
 break;
 case violet:
 break;
}
```

значит в зависимости от цвета. Всё. Ну цвет. И что? Определено только какими он может быть, но не каков он. А

```
TColor Color;
Color=ReadPixel(x, y);
switch (Color)
{
 case red:
 break;
 case orange:
 break;
 case yellow:
 break;
 case green:
 break;
 case blue:
 break;
 case violet:
 break;
}
```

– это уже в зависимости от цвета пиксела по координатам (x, y). Цвет пиксела конкретен, поэтому с ним уже можно работать.

Comment: У тебя, имя переменной Color, а ты имя пихаешь в switch...

Comment: Чем суть ответа отличается от принятого? Не говоря уже о том, что код содержит синтаксические ошибки, и его невозможно скомпилировать.

Comment: И где же там ошибки?

Comment: В объявлении типа с круглыми скобками.

Comment: короткие имена вроде `red` могут конфликтовать с простыми переменными / функциями в коде. Имя желательно задавать большими буквами и можно в отдельном пространстве имён.

Comment: Серьёзно? red конфликтует с именами функций? И что же делают эти функции? Красят что-то в красный? А ничего, что интерфейс принтера устроен иначе?